# How do you load multiple schema in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I need to compare the results of muliple schema using Solr.

Is there any way to acheive this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what comparison do you intend to do? how different are the schemas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single index defines a unified schema for all entities, however you can use multiple indexes by using solr multicore concept. please refer to http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin .

You can configure each schema as a separate core to maintain the separation how ever you can still use all the cores to search by adding following param to the request url

**shards="core_url1, core_url2, ..."**

Comment: is it possible whether it will work for different schema...? Because both schema are entirely different...